Minimum and maximum sum of numbers and sum of squares
If $x_1,x_2,...,x_n,...x_{2n}$ be non negative numbers such that
$x_1+x_2+...+x_n+...+x_{2n}=1$,
we need to find the minimum and maximum value of
$\sum_{i=1}^nx_i$ +$\sum_{j=n+1}^{2n}x_j^2$.
As $x_j^2\le x_j$ the sun $\sum_{i=1}^nx_i$ +$\sum_{i=n+1}^{2n}x_j^2 \le \sum_{i=1}^{2n}x_i=1$. Hence the maximum value is 1.
For the minimum value, $\sum_{i=n+1}^{2n}x_j^2$ will contribute to lower values than $\sum_{i=1}^nx_i$. So, by setting $x_{1}=x_{2}=...=x_{n}=0$ and $x_{n+1}=x_{n+1}=...=x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{n}$, we will get the minimum as $\frac{1}{n}$. Is there a mathematical way to prove the minimum value case.
As guided by the comments, I tried using LM.
$L=\sum_{i=1}^nx_i$ +$\sum_{j=n+1}^{2n}x_j^2 +\lambda( \sum_{i=1}^{2n}x_i-1)$. On solving, I am getting $\lambda=-1$ and $x_j=\frac{1}{2}$ which doesn't satisfy the given constraint. So, I am stuck.

Use Lagrange Multipliers.

Use $\sum_{i=n+1}^{2n}x_i^2 \ge \frac{(\sum_{i=n+1}^{2n}x_i)^2}{n}$.

Note that for $n = 1$, the minimum doesn't occur at $x_1 = 0, x_1 = 1$ for a value of $1$. Instead it occurs at $x_ 1 = 1/2, x_2 = 1/2$ for a value of $3/4$. Use River's hint to complete it.

@geetha290krm Can you please explain how to use LM here

LM easily gives $x_i=0$ for $i \le n$. Please show your effort.

@geetha290krm Problem I have is, the result of $\lambda $ doesn't satisfy the constraint.

If $\lambda =-1$ you will have $2x_j+\lambda x_j=0$ (or $2x_j=x_j$) for $n <j \le 2n$ which makes each $x_i$ equal to $0$. But that violates the given condition. So $\lambda =-1$ is ruled out. And this  gives $x_i=0$ for $i \le n$. Thus you have to minimize/maximize  $\sum_{j=n+1}^{2n}x_j^2$ subsject to $\sum_{j=n+1}^{2n}x_j=1$. Can you now finish?

Let $s:=x_1+\dots+x_n$ and $y_j:=x_{n+j}$. We want to determine
$$m(n):=\min_{0\le s\le1}\left(s+f_n(s)\right)$$
where
$$f_n(s):=\min_{y_1,\dots,y_n\ge0\atop\sum y_j=1-s}\sum_{j=1}^ny_j^2=\frac{(1-s)^2}n$$
(by Cauchy-Schwarz).
$$s+f_n(s)=\frac{s^2+(n-2)s+1}n.$$
Therefore, $m(1)=\frac34$ (attained for $s=\frac12$) and
$$\forall n\ge2\quad m(n)=\frac1n$$ (attained for $s=0$).
